# Is this integral correctly simplified?

Tags: definite-integrals

I'm working on calculating lift of an supersonic airfoil. It involves this calculation. I did a lot of calculations, realizing it might really equal this. Can someone please read this integral, and see if I simplified it correctly?

[Integral Simplified](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0Se5.png)

Comment: I would recommend writing out the calculation in LaTex onto this post or at least embedding the picture. If you make an effort in your post, you're more likely to have someone make an effort to answer your question.

Comment: My bad, I've embedded the picture into the post. Hope someone will help now

Comment: It is OK. A bit long-winded though.

Comment: I agree with @ancientmathematician .